# Xamarin Binding Library with dagger dependency

Tags: xamarin

I have a Binding Project which references a vendor's AAR file. I can get it to compile, then on run it started to throw a

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dagger.internal.factory"

So I went and found the version of dagger that the vendor uses in their example project, added it as a InputJar on the Android project (not the binding project). Now I get a new error message.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dagger.internal.Preconditions"

I'm using VS2019, with D8. Multi-dex is not enabled, different errors then, and proguard is not enabled. What am I missing to get those classes in my compiled app?

Comment: You can try to enable the `Multi-dex`  option.

Comment: I enabled that, then received an error that "dagger.internal.factory" was not found during the build step. Along with "com.google.gson.TypeAdapter".

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: I was having a similar issue with the latest Firebase libraries. Manually installing the latest version of Xamarin.Google.Dagger resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To fix all of this, I found the vendor AAR file on Maven Repistory. The Gradle Extension for Visual Studio might have fixed this but was crashing for me.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stripe/stripeterminal/1.0.0-b7

I had to download all the compile dependencies, then grab their compile dependencies and include them in my binding library as a "EmbededReferenceJAR". I do not have ProGuard running, or R8. I did have to clean the obj/Debug directory and do a Solution->Clean as well.

The issue with D8 and Multi-dex seemed to be an issue where my Visual Studio 2017 project file had some issues. I created a brand new Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2019 which solved those issues.